# Compare two complex hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, yaml

I'm trying to compare two hashes recursively in ruby, but there are some caveats. I can't simply compare the strings because one hash uses nil and one uses 0 etc

Here is my function:

```
    def compare_yaml(yaml1,yaml2)
    f = ["f", "false", false]
    t = ["t", "true", true]
    nil_equivalents = [0, "", [], {}, nil, " "]
    return true if yaml1 == yaml2

    if (f.include?(yaml1) and f.include?(yaml2)) or (t.include?(yaml1) and t.include?(yaml2))
      return true
    end
    if (nil_equivalents.include?(yaml1) && nil_equivalents.include?(yaml2)) then
        # puts "we found a nil"
    return true
    end
    if (yaml1.class == yaml2.class)
        if yaml1.class.to_s == "Hash"
            puts "gotta hash" + yaml1.to_s
            # a = yaml1.inspect
            # b = yaml2.inspect
            yaml1.keys.map{|k| (yaml2.keys.include? k)? compare_yaml(yaml1[k], yaml2[k]) : false}.reduce{|n,m| n&&m}
        end
        if yaml1.class.to_s == "Array"
            return false unless yaml1.length == yaml2.length
            # yaml1.sort!
            # yaml2.sort!
            return yaml1.zip(yaml2).map { |e| compare_yaml(e[0],e[1])}.reduce{|n,m| n&&m}

        end

    end

return false
end
```

I try to test if with the following line:

```
compare_yaml({"Computer"=>{"Axiom Tech Co"=>{"Windows 2003"=>[["x86 Family 6 Model 14 Stepping 8 ", nil, 1]]}, "Dell"=>{"Windows 2003"=>[["x86 Family 15 Model 4 Stepping 1 ", nil, 1]]}}, "Desktop"=>{"Hewlett-Packard"=>{"Windows 7 Pro"=>[["Intel Core i7 870 2.93GHz", 1, 1]], "Windows XP Pro"=>[["AMD Athlon Dual Core 4450B", 1, 1]]}}, "Laptop"=>{"Hewlett-Packard"=>{"Windows 7 Pro"=>[["Intel Core i5 M 460 2.53GHz", 1, 1]]}}},{"Computer"=>{"Axiom Tech Co"=>{"Windows 2003"=>[["x86 Family 6 Model 14 Stepping 8", 0, 1]]}, "Dell"=>{"Windows 2003"=>[["x86 Family 15 Model 4 Stepping 1", 0, 1]]}}, "Desktop"=>{"Hewlett Packard"=>{"Windows 7 Pro"=>[["Intel Core i7 870 2.93GHz", 1, 1]], "Windows XP Pro"=>[["AMD Athlon Dual Core 4450B", 1, 1]]}}, "Laptop"=>{"Hewlett Packard"=>{"Windows 7 Pro"=>[["Intel Core i5 M 460 2.53GHz", 1, 1]]}}})
```

which should return true, but it does not

Can anybody help?

Comment: How do you conclude hashes are equal?

Answer (score 0):

Your sample should return false because:

1. `"x86 Family 6 Model 14 Stepping 8 " != "x86 Family 6 Model 14 Stepping 8"` (there is a space at the end of the first)
2. `"x86 Family 15 Model 4 Stepping 1 " != "x86 Family 15 Model 4 Stepping 1"` (same thing)
3. `{"Hewlett-Packard"=>{"Windows 7 Pro"=>[["Intel Core i5 M 460 2.53GHz", 1, 1]]}}} != {"Hewlett Packard"=>{"Windows 7 Pro"=>[["Intel Core i7 870 2.93GHz", 1, 1]], "Windows XP Pro"=>[["AMD Athlon Dual Core 4450B", 1, 1]]}}` (the first one is missing "Windows XP Pro")
4. `"Hewlett Packard" != "Hewlett-Packard"`

and on and on...

bottom line - your sample should *not* return true...